# How to make an element stay on same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying out some things with a material designe framework but some things just won't work.
Here is what i got:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsMPx.png)

But I want the text to start on the top and stay there so the text won't jump into another line like in the picture.
I hope you guys can help me.

```html
<p><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="W3Schools.com" width="100" height="140">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Comment: Can you share your code so we can point out where the problem is?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table, like this:

```
<table><tr><th><img src="yourimgsrc.jpeg"></th><th><p>Your text here</p></th></tr></table>
```

This prevents your problem, because the two rows (`<th>`) end on the same height

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. You will have to have both, the IMG and the text in one `<div>` and then surround both of them in a separate `<div>`

```css
#header{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}

#column1{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;

}


#column2{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="column1"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="W3Schools.com" width="100" height="140"></div>
    <div id="column2"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div>
</div>
```